# uploading image from ACF image thru phone not working

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

here's my code to submit post from frontend using ACF, all of this are working fine in desktop but when I tried to post using phone the image appears in media library but not in CPT, does anyone here have any idea? thanks

```
$user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
                $args = array(
                    'post_id'       => 'new_post',
                    'field_groups'  => array(570), //it's the ID of your custom field Form
                    'form' => false,
                    'new_post'      => array(
                                'post_type'     => 'team_member',
                                'post_status'   => 'pending',
                                'post_title'    => $user_info->user_login),
                );
                acf_form( $args );
```

**Function.php**

```
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

// bail early if not a new post
if( $post_id !== 'new_post' ) {
     
    return $post_id;
    
}
    

$my_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'team_member'
                            
    );
// insert the post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

}